# Where is the code Tensorflow uses to implement RMSProp

Tags: python, tensorflow, mathematical-optimization

I've cloned Tensorflow from `https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git` and am trying to find the code where RMS_Prop is implemented.

I have found the file `tensorflow/tensorflow/python/training/rmsprop.py`, which has calls to `training_ops.apply_centered_rms_prop` and to `training_ops.apply_rms_prop`, which seem to be the methods I'm looking for.

I can see that `rmsprop.py` imports `training ops` with this import statement:

```
from tensorflow.python.training import training_ops
```

but, when I look at `training_ops.py`, all I see is the following code:

"""Python wrappers for training ops."""

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

from tensorflow.python.training import gen_training_ops  # pylint: disable=unused-import
# go/tf-wildcard-import
# pylint: disable=wildcard-import
from tensorflow.python.training.gen_training_ops import *
# pylint: enable=wildcard-import
```

I do not see `gen_training_ops` in the `tensorflow/tensorflow/python/training` directory and the `__init__` file is empty.

What is it I'm not understanding here, and where can I find the *actual* code that directly implements rmsprop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main computational code is implemented in C++; the Python layer abstracts this. The files you are interested in are the [CPU kernel](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/83d65b152b6b1ed1e622c59d908e76d8d2e7d07b/tensorflow/core/kernels/training_ops.cc) and [GPU kernel](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/96c5c8a65e388d8d3821d04d919df907de114a5d/tensorflow/core/kernels/training_ops_gpu.cu.cc). The kernel for RMSProp starts on lines 500 and 408 respectively.